# identify the last 2 weeks of the last quarter month

Tags: validation, validation-rule, date

I do not want the user to save the CloseDate as the last 2 weeks of the last quarter month.
for ex. March 16-31 / June 16-30  / Sept 16-30 / Dec 16-31

Currently I am trying to use a validation rule and I am starting to think that it is not possible with dynamic ranges.

```
OR( 
CloseDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MOD(MONTH(TODAY()), 3),16) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This validation rule formula should work for your purposes:

```
AND( 
  MOD(MONTH(CloseDate), 3) = 0, 
  DAY(CloseDate) > 15 
)
```

I believe you can get fancier and more dynamic/configurable than this, but if you don't expect the rule to change much from your current requirement this should suffice.

Comment: thanks I was trying to use greater than but it wouldn't let me in the date format